# Accidentally pushed from another folder to github

Tags: git, github

I have 2 folders of the same project and accidentally made 2 pushes (8f6136a first and then 0c44706) from the wrong folder and I want to revert back to an older commit (67dff53). 
How can i go about doing that?

Comment: git reset --hard 67dff53 and then do a force push from your local to origin

Comment: Thanks @karthick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the remote repository is shared then you'll need to revert the commits starting with the most recent first:

1. `git revert 0c44706`
2. `git revert 8f6136a`
3. `git push` these changes to the remote

This isn't an option if others have access to the remote repository but if you're in the fortunate position where only you have access to this repository then you can reset the tip of your branch to `67dff53` and push it up:

1. `git reset --hard 67dff53`
2. `git push -f` to push this to the remote branch

Comment: I made a hard reset then force pushed, worked like a charm! Thanks alot